# How to select first occurrence of a string in group 1 in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am having the below string as input -

```
Title : Mr
Name : ABC
value :  4
contact no. : +62337282XXXX
Name : ABC  
value :  5
Name : ABC
value :  6
contact no. : +62337282XXXX
Name : ABC  
value :  7
```

Used regex - `Name\s+.\s+(.*)(?=.*\n)`

But it is selecting both the name.
How to select only the first occurrence here please advise,

Comment: It's not really a good idea to make an html parser out of regexes. Better use an html parser. For one thing, you can't really on line separators as they are arbitrary to html

Comment: It seems not a problem with the pattern, share your code.

Comment: @Alireza Name\s+.\s+(.*)(?=.*\n)

Comment: What exactly do you want to select from this string?

Comment: @Alireza only the ABC

Comment: You just need to use `if` not `while`

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(?<=^Name : )\w+(?=\n)`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wfo0I0/3)

Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(?<=^Name : )\\w+(?=\\n)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String input = "Name : ABC\n" +
                "value :  4\n" +
                "contact no. : +62337282XXXX\n" +
                "Name : ABC\n" +
                "value :  5";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output: `ABC`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you try with the full string above.

Name : ABC
value :  4
contact no. : +62337282XXXX
Name : ABC
value :  5

Comment: No problem with full string.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could do for complete string till value : 5

Comment: Thats worked like charm ! but what if i have four times ABC in the question, i have updated now.

Comment: Go in code and replace it with a new string to see "what if i have four times ABC in the question". nothing changes still select the first ABC

Comment: what we can do if we add (Title : Mr) at the top ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a counter and break the loop as soon as the counter has reached the required value (e.g. 1 in this case).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        
        String data = "Name : ABC\n"
                + "value :  4\n"
                + "contact no. : +62337282XXXX\n"
                + "Name : ABC  \n"
                + "value :  5\n"
                + "Name : ABC\n"
                + "value :  6\n"
                + "contact no. : +62337282XXXX\n"
                + "Name : ABC  \n"
                + "value :  7";
        
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Name\\s+.\\s+(.*)(?=.*\\n)").matcher(data);
        
        while(count != 1 && matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name : ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Name\\s+.\\s+(.*)(?=.*\\n)");
String input = String.join(
        "\n",
        "Name : ABC",
        "value :  4",
        "contact no. : +62337282XXXX",
        "Name : ABC",
        "value :  5");

Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
if (match.find()) {
    String firstMatch = match.group();
    System.out.println(firstMatch);
}
```

For more information check out the reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the regex still selected ABC twice. Could you please check again,